# JavaScript onClick Event Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to add an onClick event to the buttons I created here: https://makerlist.io/smart-feature-finder/. I am adding a "Hello, World!" statement that appears when the button is clicked to test it. Here is the code I'm using, however nothing appears. Any ideas on what I am missing?

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".esg-filterbutton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    alert ("Hello, World!");
}
```

Thanks,

Jonahan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector returns an array-like object known as a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) not a single element.

Try,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("esg-filterbutton")[0].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Notice I'm grabbing the first element in the array?

Also I removed the `.` before the name of the class. As you are specifying that you want to select a class in the function, you don't need to put a `.`.

Comment: Technically it is not an array, it is a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: @epascarello It is an array-like object. Array is merely my way of explaining it in layman's terms. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Works! Thanks @Script47.

Comment: But what if I want to assign a function to all elements of the class, not just the first one?  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a `click` event to the element with class `esg-filterbutton` if you wish to apply the event to all your buttons.

```
$('.esg-filterbutton').click(function()
{
    alert ("Hello, World!");
});
```

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/Lb1wj47j/